# How does Postgres host based authentication work?

Tags: postgresql, dspace, pg-hba.conf

I am installing DSPACE which needs PostgresSQL.

Please see this link: [DSPACE INSTALL](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace)

It says:

> Then tighten up security a bit by editing pg_hba.conf and adding this line:
>
> ```
> host dspace dspace 127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 md5.
> ```

I have read on the internet as to how the above line works. It needs a connection type followed by database name/user name followed by IP address and the authentication scheme.

My question is: Should this not be a local (in place of host) connection since the dspace user is running locally?

Can someone show me step by step as to what happens when a request comes in?
Where are the instructions that the dspace user will submit a request using md5?

Comment: This might be better asked on the sister site, DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSpace uses JDBC, so `local` won't work for it.  Here `local` means a completely different kind of inter-process connection that has nothing to do with IP and can only address local processes:  Unix sockets.  JDBC uses only IP, so DSpace needs a `host` descriptor.

That period at the end of the line is not supposed to be part of it.  The documentation was unclear there -- I've fixed it.

As Laurenz Albe noted, DSpace doesn't specify that MD5 password hashes be used.  The PostgreSQL server controls which methods will be tried, based on what you specify in `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a `.` at the end of your `pg_hba.conf` line. That is a syntax error.

Whether to use `local` or `host` depends on

- what API this DSPACE is using (JDBC, for example, allows no UNIX socket connections)
- what connection string DSPACE is using

If you can specify a socket directory as host name, you can probably use UNIX sockets, which would be more efficient.

If DSPACE uses a driver that supports `md5` authentication, the procedure is like this:

- client sends server a connect packet with user and database
- server requests `md5` authentication and sends a random "salt" string
- client computes an MD5 hash of the password with the salt from the server and sends the result to the server
- server verifies that the hash is correct